# Transferring an Excel Moving Average Calculator to R

Tags: r

so I've been trying to teach myself R and have a calculator I created in excel that I'm trying to get working in R.

In R, I'd like to calculate a 45 day moving average based on loan prices I have. The data sample in excel is here:

[image]

dput output in R is here:

```
    > dput(data)
structure(list(`usd price` = c(50000, 60000, 40000, 35000, 1e+05, 
95000), `cad price` = c(62500, 75000, 50000, 43750, 125000, 118750
), day = structure(c(1642118400, 1641772800, 1639958400, 1639785600, 
1638316800, 1640995200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Loan = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

In excel, I can do the following formulas (in yellow) to get the correct 45 day moving average result (in blue):
[image: excel formulas]

The written out logic is:

1. Filter out "Loan" = FALSE values
2. Filter out the outliers defined as the top 25% of the previous 45 day values of "usd price" (including the day of)
3. Calculate the 45 day average of USD price for the remaining values

Hopefully this makes sense so far. I am having trouble filtering out the top 25% of values in the 45 day set for each row. Here's my R code so far:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(day=lubridate::parse_date_time(day, "ymd"))

data = data %>%
  filter(Loan=="TRUE")%>%
  mutate(fourtyfive_avg= rollmean('usd_price',45,
                             align="right",
                             fill=0)) %>%
  relocate(fourtyfive_avg)
```

This gives me MA's for each record which I want, but I need to filter out the top quartile before making the MA calculation.

Comment: If you are fine with removing the record from the dataset `filter(usd_price < quantile(usd_price, probs = 0.75))`. Either way, `quantile` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: i need to remove that quantile in the previous 45 days worth of data for each row though

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question perhaps. Your data in your Excel example doesn't seem to be organized correctly so I'm not sure your expected results are what you're asking for. USD price 100,000 is the first value by day (12/1/2021) so if you were using a moving average that should display 100,000 for the moving average based on what you're saying.

Comment: yes, the moving average result would be $100k on that day. BUT $100k is in the top quartile of the range, so it should be filtered out. Does that make more sense?

Comment: still a bit confused with respect to differences in your description vs calculation for your quantiles, but see my answer which should cover either scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s one way to do it I suppose. Not super efficient because it’s not vectorized, but if your dataset isn’t huge it should work. I made some assumptions on what the result should be because your example calculations and description don’t match. The quartiles in your Excel calculations are across all dates and not just the previous 45 days. I’ve done the calculation so outliers are considered only for the previous 45 days (as you’ve described you want), not across all the data.

If `Loan` is `FALSE` I’ve just returned `NA`, but you could calculate the 45 day average for that date as well using the values in that window that have `Loan == TRUE`. If it’s the first value in a 45 day window, the result will be that value.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
```

```r
data <- 
  structure(list(`usd price` = c(50000, 60000, 40000, 35000, 1e+05, 
  95000), `cad price` = c(62500, 75000, 50000, 43750, 125000, 118750
  ), day = structure(c(1642118400, 1641772800, 1639958400, 1639785600, 
  1638316800, 1640995200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
      Loan = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

data <- data %>% mutate(day=lubridate::parse_date_time(day, "ymd"))
```

```r
myfunc <- function(x){
  fourtyfive_days <- as.Date(x - ddays(45))
  
  if(!data$Loan[data$day %in% x]) return(NA)
  
  data <-
    data %>%
    filter(day <= x) %>%
    filter(day >= fourtyfive_days) %>%
    filter(Loan) %>%
    filter(`usd price` <= quantile(`usd price`, probs = 0.75)) %>% 
    summarize(fourtyfive_avg = mean(`usd price`))
  
    return(data$fourtyfive_avg)
}
data$fourtyfive_avg <- sapply(data$day, simplify = TRUE,  FUN = myfunc)
```

To match your calculation and not the description:

```r
myfunc <- function(x){
  fourtyfive_days <- as.Date(x - ddays(45))
  
  if(!data$Loan[data$day %in% x]) return(NA)
  
  data <-
    data %>%
    filter(Loan) %>%
    filter(`usd price` <= quantile(`usd price`, probs = 0.75)) %>% 
    filter(day <= x) %>%
    filter(day >= fourtyfive_days) %>%
    summarize(fourtyfive_avg = mean(`usd price`))
  
    return(data$fourtyfive_avg)
}
data$fourtyfive_avg <- sapply(data$day, simplify = TRUE,  FUN = myfunc)

data %>% arrange(day)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   `usd price` `cad price` day                 Loan  fourtyfive_avg
#>         <dbl>       <dbl> <dttm>              <lgl>          <dbl>
#> 1      100000      125000 2021-12-01 00:00:00 TRUE             NaN
#> 2       35000       43750 2021-12-18 00:00:00 TRUE           35000
#> 3       40000       50000 2021-12-20 00:00:00 TRUE           37500
#> 4       95000      118750 2022-01-01 00:00:00 FALSE             NA
#> 5       60000       75000 2022-01-10 00:00:00 TRUE           45000
#> 6       50000       62500 2022-01-14 00:00:00 TRUE           46250
```

Comment: thanks, this is it! Any suggestions for making it more efficient?

Comment: @Ranalytictsnewb R is a language that works most efficiently when you are working with vectors. With what I've done, you're effectively looping through the data (i.e. not doing it all on one vector). If you can figure out a way to do it so all the calculations are on a vector rather than looping, that would be more efficient. It could be easy or difficult depending on what you actually want with your outlier calculation, but there's likely time window calculations in packages like `zoo` that could help. If your data is small it doesn't matter too much though.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? I have defined a variable `ndays` to test with the posted data.
Also note that since `Loan` is a logical variable, there is no need to test the equality with `TRUE` or `"TRUE"`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

ndays <- 2

data %>%
  filter(Loan) %>%
  arrange(day) %>%
  mutate(q45days = rollapplyr(`usd price`, ndays, quantile, prob = 0.75, fill = NA)) %>%
  filter(`usd price` < q45days) %>%
  select(-q45days) %>%
  mutate(fourtyfive_avg= rollmeanr(`usd price`, 45, fill = 0)) %>%
  relocate(fourtyfive_avg)
```

Comment: hmm, it's running, but for some reason, the fourtyfive_avg first column in the resulting tibble is 0'd out., so when I view(data) the column doesn't appear